# Select All Query in DataTable doesn't get items if column is time

Tags: c#, datatable, oledb

I am currently using query

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]
```

in OLEDB. The problem is the column is date and under that column has string. The string are missing after querying select all. Is there a way to select all and change the datatype of the column at the same time?

Comment: Can post your code? clarify your answer a bit more with images.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you are using Excel file for OLEDB data connection.

There is an option in Excel to format the column datatype!

Select the column, click on "Number Format" icon in ribbon, Select custom format.

Apply "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm" format or you can change it as per your requirement. it will change datatype for entire column.

[image]

Now if any data is not entered properly according to this date-time format, that data will display as `NULL` in OLEDB collection.